# symfony php script run by crontab give loop

Tags: php, symfony

my system generate invoices each day 1 at month. First he get list of customers of A-Z then got your invoice. When i open with Browser(like chrome) its works fine. But when i run by crontab, the loop restart and generate many times the same task.

Sample, while they is generating invoice from cliente M they back to first A and generate again. If i not kill the cron and apache he will generate many times the same invoice.

My crontab -e

```
0 0 1 * * wget -O - http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/consult/crontab/db/30d >/dev/null 2>&1
```

My code is simple,

```
$getLists = $repositoryCustomer->get();
...  
foreach($getLists as $customer){
   $invoice = $this->generateAction($keyCustomer,$begin,$end);
   $key = explode("/",$invoice->getTargetUrl());
   if ($invoice->getPos()){
       $run = $this->forward('AppBundle:Calls:register',array(
              'datakey'=>end($key)));
   }
   $this->printAction(end($invoice));
   $this->forward('AppBundle:Customer:sendInvoice',array(
                'datakey'=>end($key)
            ));
}
```

The code is only that and works, until i try run in crontab. 
One detail, for generating the invoices he system consult two databases out, one oracle ( 20 minutes or more to return one search ) and another mysql ( 1min to return ). The invoices faster generate more times.

I check the list of customers and each customer has one time. If customer has one time, why they restart the loop and generate again the same invoice period?

How can fix that?

Comment: Did you `dump` or `var_dump` step by step your code to see what really happened in *crontab* request?

Comment: how is the best way to log this? wget to be dump in null.

Comment: I don't know the best way but you can return dumped result as Json or another format and use [cron-job online](https://cron-job.org/en/) to create cronjob online and track the result.

Comment: Great, testing now... thank you.

Comment: No problem. good luck